# Prove that the number of beautiful positive integers in the set $\{ 2^{20},\; 2^{20}+1,\; 2^{20}+2, \; ..., \; 2^{21}-1 \}$ is divisible by 17

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, contest-math

*Definition*. Let a positive integer $n$ be written in binary numeral system. We shall say that a some digit of the $n$ is interesting if this digit is not equal to the adjacent digit to the right of it and if this digit is not equal adjacent digit to the left of it (The first digit is interesting if it is not equal to the second digit. The last digit is interesting if it is not equal to the penultimate digit). Let $f(n)$ be the number of interesting digits of $n$. If $f(n)=16$ then we shall say that the positive integer $n$ is beautiful.

> Let $k$ be the number of beautiful positive integers in the set $\{ 2^{20},\; 2^{20}+1,\; 2^{20}+2, \; ..., \; 2^{21}-1 \}$. Prove that $k$ is divisible by $17$.

**My work**. Using a computer program, I found that $k=323$. Below I wrote all the beautiful positive integers in binary numeral system. But I need to have a mathematical solution of the problem.

111110101010101010101,
111011010101010101010,
111010110101010101010,
111010101101010101010,
111010101011010101010,
111010101010110101010,
111010101010101101010,
111010101010101011010,
111010101010101010110,
111010101010101010100,
111010101010101010010,
111010101010101001010,
111010101010100101010,
111010101010010101010,
111010101001010101010,
111010100101010101010,
111010010101010101010,
111001010101010101010,
110111010101010101010,
110101110101010101010,
110101011101010101010,
110101010111010101010,
110101010101110101010,
110101010101011101010,
110101010101010111010,
110101010101010101110,
110101010101010101000,
110101010101010100010,
110101010101010001010,
110101010101000101010,
110101010100010101010,
110101010001010101010,
110101000101010101010,
110100010101010101010,
110001010101010101010,
101111101010101010101,
101110110101010101010,
101110101101010101010,
101110101011010101010,
101110101010110101010,
101110101010101101010,
101110101010101011010,
101110101010101010110,
101110101010101010100,
101110101010101010010,
101110101010101001010,
101110101010100101010,
101110101010010101010,
101110101001010101010,
101110100101010101010,
101110010101010101010,
101101110101010101010,
101101011101010101010,
101101010111010101010,
101101010101110101010,
101101010101011101010,
101101010101010111010,
101101010101010101110,
101101010101010101000,
101101010101010100010,
101101010101010001010,
101101010101000101010,
101101010100010101010,
101101010001010101010,
101101000101010101010,
101100010101010101010,
101011111010101010101,
101011101101010101010,
101011101011010101010,
101011101010110101010,
101011101010101101010,
101011101010101011010,
101011101010101010110,
101011101010101010100,
101011101010101010010
101011101010101001010,
101011101010100101010,
101011101010010101010,
101011101001010101010,
101011100101010101010,
101011011101010101010,
101011010111010101010,
101011010101110101010,
101011010101011101010,
101011010101010111010,
101011010101010101110,
101011010101010101000,
101011010101010100010,
101011010101010001010,
101011010101000101010,
101011010100010101010,
101011010001010101010,
101011000101010101010,
101010111110101010101,
101010111011010101010,
101010111010110101010,
101010111010101101010,
101010111010101011010,
101010111010101010110,
101010111010101010100,
101010111010101010010,
101010111010101001010,
101010111010100101010,
101010111010010101010,
101010111001010101010,
101010110111010101010,
101010110101110101010,
101010110101011101010,
101010110101010111010,
101010110101010101110,
101010110101010101000,
101010110101010100010,
101010110101010001010,
101010110101000101010,
101010110100010101010,
101010110001010101010,
101010101111101010101,
101010101110110101010,
101010101110101101010,
101010101110101011010,
101010101110101010110,
101010101110101010100,
101010101110101010010,
101010101110101001010,
101010101110100101010,
101010101110010101010,
101010101101110101010,
101010101101011101010,
101010101101010111010,
101010101101010101110,
101010101101010101000,
101010101101010100010,
101010101101010001010,
101010101101000101010,
101010101100010101010,
101010101011111010101,
101010101011101101010,
101010101011101011010,
101010101011101010110,
101010101011101010100,
101010101011101010010,
101010101011101001010,
101010101011100101010,
101010101011011101010,
101010101011010111010,
101010101011010101110,
101010101011010101000,
101010101011010100010,
101010101011010001010,
101010101011000101010,
101010101010111110101,
101010101010111011010,
101010101010111010110,
101010101010111010100,
101010101010111010010,
101010101010111001010,
101010101010110111010,
101010101010110101110,
101010101010110101000,
101010101010110100010,
101010101010110001010,
101010101010101111101,
101010101010101110110,
101010101010101110100,
101010101010101110010,
101010101010101101110,
101010101010101101000,
101010101010101100010,
101010101010101011111,
101010101010101011100,
101010101010101011000,
101010101010101001110,
101010101010101001000,
101010101010101000110,
101010101010101000100,
101010101010101000001,
101010101010100111010,
101010101010100101110,
101010101010100101000,
101010101010100100010,
101010101010100011010,
101010101010100010110,
101010101010100010100,
101010101010100010010,
101010101010100000101,
101010101010011101010,
101010101010010111010,
101010101010010101110,
101010101010010101000,
101010101010010100010,
101010101010010001010,
101010101010001101010,
101010101010001011010,
101010101010001010110,
101010101010001010100,
101010101010001010010,
101010101010001001010,
101010101010000010101,
101010101001110101010,
101010101001011101010,
101010101001010111010,
101010101001010101110,
101010101001010101000,
101010101001010100010,
101010101001010001010,
101010101001000101010,
101010101000110101010,
101010101000101101010,
101010101000101011010,
101010101000101010110,
101010101000101010100,
101010101000101010010,
101010101000101001010,
101010101000100101010,
101010101000001010101,
101010100111010101010,
101010100101110101010,
101010100101011101010,
101010100101010111010,
101010100101010101110,
101010100101010101000,
101010100101010100010,
101010100101010001010,
101010100101000101010,
101010100100010101010,
101010100011010101010,
101010100010110101010,
101010100010101101010,
101010100010101011010,
101010100010101010110,
101010100010101010100,
101010100010101010010,
101010100010101001010,
101010100010100101010,
101010100010010101010,
101010100000101010101,
101010011101010101010,
101010010111010101010,
101010010101110101010,
101010010101011101010,
101010010101010111010,
101010010101010101110,
101010010101010101000,
101010010101010100010,
101010010101010001010,
101010010101000101010,
101010010100010101010,
101010010001010101010,
101010001101010101010,
101010001011010101010,
101010001010110101010,
101010001010101101010,
101010001010101011010,
101010001010101010110,
101010001010101010100,
101010001010101010010,
101010001010101001010,
101010001010100101010,
101010001010010101010,
101010001001010101010,
101010000010101010101,
101001110101010101010,
101001011101010101010,
101001010111010101010,
101001010101110101010,
101001010101011101010,
101001010101010111010,
101001010101010101110,
101001010101010101000,
101001010101010100010,
101001010101010001010,
101001010101000101010,
101001010100010101010,
101001010001010101010,
101001000101010101010,
101000110101010101010,
101000101101010101010,
101000101011010101010,
101000101010110101010,
101000101010101101010,
101000101010101011010,
101000101010101010110,
101000101010101010100,
101000101010101010010,
101000101010101001010,
101000101010100101010,
101000101010010101010,
101000101001010101010,
101000100101010101010,
101000001010101010101,
100111010101010101010,
100101110101010101010,
100101011101010101010,
100101010111010101010,
100101010101110101010,
100101010101011101010,
100101010101010111010,
100101010101010101110,
100101010101010101000,
100101010101010100010,
100101010101010001010,
100101010101000101010,
100101010100010101010,
100101010001010101010,
100101000101010101010,
100100010101010101010,
100011010101010101010,
100010110101010101010,
100010101101010101010,
100010101011010101010,
100010101010110101010,
100010101010101101010,
100010101010101011010,
100010101010101010110,
100010101010101010100,
100010101010101010010,
100010101010101001010,
100010101010100101010,
100010101010010101010,
100010101001010101010,
100010100101010101010,
100010010101010101010,
100000101010101010101,

Comment: Could you include the binary representations in a link or only include the beautiful numbers? The entire list is rather long to include in this post. This is a really interesting question, though.

Comment: Soham Konar  In this list are only  beautiful numbers. I do not know how include the numbers in a link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Corrected**

Let me work first with all $21$-bit strings instead of just those that begin with $1$. One of these strings is beautiful iff it has exactly $5$ uninteresting bits. A bit is uninteresting if it is equal to a neighboring bit, in which case the neighboring bit is also uninteresting. In fact, it’s not hard to see that the uninteresting bits are precisely the ones that occur in blocks of two or more consecutive identical bits; call these the non-trivial blocks. For example, the non-trivial blocks of $10\color{red}{111}010101\color{red}{00}10101010$ are shown in red. Thus, a beautiful string either has a single non-trival block of length $5$, or has two non-trivial blocks, one of length $2$ and one of length $3$.

Suppose that a beautiful string has a single non-trivial block of length $5$. Number the bits $1$ through $21$ from left to right. The non-trivial block can start at any of the first $17$ bits, and can be either $00000$ or $11111$. Once you’ve picked the starting point and whether it is a block of zeroes or a block of ones, the rest of the beautiful string is completely determined, so there are $2\cdot17$ such beautiful strings.

Now suppose that a beautiful number has a non-trivial block of length $2$ and a non-trivial block of length $3$. If these blocks are adjacent, they form a string of $5$ bits that is either $00111$, $11000$, $00011$, or $11100$. As before, this string can start in any of the first $17$ positions, so there are $4\cdot17$ beautiful strings of this type.

If the $2$-block and the $3$-block are **not** adjacent, let $k$ be the number of bits between them. The string consisting of the two blocks and the $k$ bits between them has length $k+5$, so it can start at any of the first $17-k$ positions. If $k$ is odd, the two blocks must be of the same type, either both of them blocks of zeroes, or both of them blocks of ones. If $k$ is even, they must be of opposite types. Moreover, the $2$-block can be at either end of the string, so for each starting position there are $4$ possible beautiful strings, and each possible value of $k$ produces $4(17-k)=4\cdot17-4k$ beautiful strings. Finally, $k$ can be any integer from $1$ through $17$, so this case accounts for

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{17}(4\cdot17-4k)&=4\cdot17^2-4\sum_{k=1}^{17}k\\
&=4\cdot17^2-4\cdot\frac{17\cdot18}2\\
&=17(68-36)\\
&=32\cdot17
\end{align*}$$

beautiful strings.

There are therefore $2\cdot17+4\cdot17+32\cdot17=38\cdot17=646$ beautiful strings.

If $\sigma$ is a string, let $\hat\sigma$ be the string that results from $\sigma$ by replacing each $0$ by $1$ and each $1$ by $0$; clearly $\sigma$ is beautiful iff $\hat\sigma$ is beautiful, so exactly half of the beautiful strings begin with $1$ and are beautiful numbers. Thus, there are $19\cdot17=323$ beautiful numbers, which is indeed a multiple of $17$.

Comment: Thank you! I think I found you have an error. You write that "there are $2⋅17$ such beautiful numbers". But you did not take into account that block $00000$ cannot start from the first position, because the first digit is always equel one. Hence, there are $16+17$ such beautiful numbers.

Comment: @Witold: Ah, you’re right: by the time I was writing it up, I’d forgotten that we were dealing with numbers that are at least $2^{20}$ and not just with $21$-bit strings. That’s going to affect some of the other figures as well.

Comment: @Witold: Fixed, and your count of $323$ is now confirmed.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @Witold: You’re welcome! It’s a cute problem.

Comment: Actually, you don't need to split up the cases, (if all that you care about is showing it's a multiple of 17).

Comment: @CalvinLin: I realized when I wrote it up that the cases could be combined, but for pædagogical reasons I decided to leave it in the form in which I came up with the argument.